# git submodules using .gitmodules - failing to to take the latest code from master

Tags: git, git-submodules

using this:
`git pull && git submodule init && git submodule update && git submodule status`

`.gitmodules`

```
[submodule "Backend"]
    path = Backend
    url = git@github.com:OwnHealthIL/Backend.git
    branch = master
    checkout = master
```

for some reason, the git submodule checks out to an old tag.

how can I tell git submodule to pull the lastest HEAD ?

Comment: Maybe master is point out to this tag? have you verified it?

Comment: what do you mean pointing to this tag? the HEAD currently is not this tag.

Comment: This is an unlikely scenario as per me, but probably you can deinit submodule and initialise it all over again. No harm in that.